# Python (or etc.) - Process HTML to add target=blank to a-tags not in domain list

Tags: python, html, regex

I write web content for a living. I compose in markdown and process out with pandoc, because I have to submit HTML files.

All outbound links need to have target="_blank" in the submitted markup. Links within the network should not. I could add {:target="_blank"} to the markdown files when composing (and also switch to Kramdown), but I'd rather deal with this in post.

I already have a little bash script that fixes some of the other output things after rendering via pandoc. I'd like to add this requirement there.

I'm imagining my little script would include a list of domain names that it would avoid. I can sort of sketch out the basic idea of this, but I don't know enough regex or text processing generally to figure out the details.

Any help?

(I have primarily used Bash for this stuff in the past, when I first started doing it and my needs [I thought] were simple. I have switched to Python for newer things, so that's what I mentioned above. I actually don't care what gets used [within reason]).

(Also -- for MY OWN stuff, I accomplish this with three-lines of Jquery on-page, instead of cluttering up my source content. I cannot convince THE MAN that this is the right course of action.)

Cheers! and Thanks!

Comment: So if I asked the question without including the details about why I'm trying to figure it out, that would be okay?

Comment: No, you need to include some code that shows what you've actually tried and how it hasn't worked.

Comment: Pandoc is scriptable, you should probably directly manipulate pandoc's AST instead of postprocessing the output HTML. See http://pandoc.org/scripting.html (you can script in Haskell, Python, or more).

Answer (score 6):

Using regular expressions for HTML... [leads to madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use a dedicated HTML processing tool, like Beautiful Soup 4.

```
html = """
<a href="http://newwindow.example.com">New window</a>
<a href="http://samewindow.example.com">Same window</a>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
href_re = re.compile(r"^http://newwindow\.example\.com")
links = soup.find_all('a', href=href_re)
for link in links:
    link['target'] = '_blank'
print unicode(soup)
```

Comment: Thank you. This gives me a starting point.